# Существуют ли CMS который работают с NoSQL?

Tags: cms, firebase

И которые можно установить на Google Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Google Firebase - это BaaS сервис. Это когда серверную часть проекта вам писать не нужно - только настроить его из интерфейса, который даёт вам BaaS.

Плюсы BaaS:
-большая экономия времени и денег на серверной разработке и поддержке
-очень шустрый бекенд

Минусы BaaS:
-это платный сервис(правда относительно недорогой)
-весь бекенд сводится к CRUD - то есть фронт под него будет написать не так уж просто
-зависимость от сторонней компании, в данном случае гугл. Однажды уже у многих поболела голова с их BaaS-ками, когда Facebook закрыл свой parse.com .

Возвращаясь к теме вопроса. То есть для BaaS нет CMS в общем понимании слова, есть то, что скорее можно назвать [JavaScript-библиотеками](https://habrahabr.ru/post/234409/) и [SDK](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277941/). И уж тем более хранилище находится внутри BaaS - то есть не ваша забота.